# GCP api call from cloud function to vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-compute-engine

I am looking to make an api call into a server I host in a compute engine. I want to make this call from cloud function. How can I do this without exposing the Compute Engine to the public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I am understanding this correctly, you have a private Cloud Function and you want it to make calls to an API on a private Compute Engine VM is that correct?

If this is the case, then what I think you need to set up a [Serverless VPC Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access).  Serverless VPC Access allows your private serverless services (i.e. CF, Cloud Run, App Engine) to connect to resources in your VPCs. You can think of it like VPC peering in a sense.